# How To Upload a File in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

HI all i have a situation  like this ......

```
      AttachmentName:[TextBox] [FileuploadControl] Add

           [Upload]Buton
```

when the user Gives the FileName and Uploads the file name and clicks on add i want to display the Attachment Name in a GridColumn and when he is finished and clicks on Upload button i want to save the file in this path

```
             string savefilename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"),
                                    Path.GetFileName());
```

and i want the uploaded file name to be Attachmentname entered in the textbox...and i wan the url of uploaded file to be saved in database...can any one give me any idea how to do this

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i had done the fileupload and saving that in a required path....after when i enter the Attachment name in a TextBox i want the value entered there to be shown in  a table or grid

Comment: going by the title of your question, [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) should help you.